# Using higher density images for lower resolution devices

Tags: android, resolution, screen-resolution, android-screen-support

I'm using Images only of the resolution `xxhdpi` to reduce the size of apk

If I run my app in `xxhdpi` device, its fine.

When I run my app in `hdpi` device it is responding very slowly.

Is this time being taken to render `xxhdpi` image in `hdpi` ??

Is this a correct procedure to use ??

Answer (score 2):

No that's not correct procedure, it is slow, sometimes it may also kill your app saying MemoryOutOfException etc...

You've to programmatically decode and downgrade the image using BitmapFactory

For example

```
//decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
    try {
        //decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

        //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
        int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
        int scale=1;
        while(!(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)){
            width_tmp/=2;
            height_tmp/=2;
            scale*=2;
        }

        //decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize=scale;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
    return null;
}
```

Comment: if you want to load image from res folder use decodeFromResource()

Comment: fine, just change the line from BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);  to  BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.unnamed, o);

Comment: when there is a list contaning 10 items with all images, I used your code and it is taking 3 seconds to load those images. It will be much worse when there are hundreds of images. am I right ??

Comment: use that function inside asynctask

Comment: wrote it in asynctask, even then it is showing empty image at the begining and then loading the images